# Silverlight version mismatch

Tags: silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

I just found out that LightSwitch 2011 is out. I tried to install it and found out that Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Service Pack 1 is a pre-requisite. I installed the Service Pack and then it allowed me to install LightSwitch 2011. All well and good.

Now when I start a new LightSwitch project, it gives me an error that "Unable to find a version of silverlight development runtime installed. Please install the silverlight development runtime." and then there's the link. I click on the link, install whatever is required and the installation fails.

After trying a couple of options I got the response from MSDN Forums that I should uninstall everything and re-install. Tried that. Same error again.

Another response on msdn forums says that my silverlight runtime and developer package must match. I check and find out that they are different versions

Developer Package: 4.0.60129.0 
Microsoft Silverlight: 4.0.51204.0

That's what's causing the problem. How can I upgrade both to the latest version and make them match?

Comment: I just realized that I just can't update my silverlight. Even after uninstalling Visual Studio 2010, I can't seem to do it. I think it is a silverlight installation issue. In fact I that reminds me, my windows update has also been failing for last couple of months due to the silverlight update.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I deleted all entries of "silverlight" from the registry manually. It was a long and painful process. It still didn't work.

I had to reinstall Windows.

It finally works now. I was able to install the latest version of silverlight and work on LightSwitch 2011 finally.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I had exactly the same problems (12 months later!). What fixed it for me was quite simple.

Instead of following the error prompt to download the latest version of Lightswitch go directly to http://www.silverlight.net/downloads and install Silverlight 5 Developer Runtime for Windows (either 64 or 32 bit).

Hope this helps!